# Lua - get command line input from user?

Tags: lua, user-input, blocking, wait

In my lua program, i want to stop and ask user for confirmation before proceeding with an operation. I'm not sure how to stop and wait for user input, how can it be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the `io` library, which by default has standard-input as the default input file:

http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html

Answer (score 34):

```
local answer
repeat
   io.write("continue with this operation (y/n)? ")
   io.flush()
   answer=io.read()
until answer=="y" or answer=="n"
```

Comment: Does `io.read()` impose automatic `io.flush()` when working with default stdin/out?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, it might, but we can't be sure. I don't think ANSI C says anything about this.

Answer (score 10):

I've worked with code like this. I will type this in a way it will work:

```
io.write("continue with this operation (y/n)?")
answer=io.read()
if answer=="y" then
   --(put what you want it to do if you say y here)
elseif answer=="n" then
   --(put what you want to happen if you say n)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
     print("Continue (y/n)?")
re = io.read()
if re == "y" or "Y" then
    (Insert stuff here)
elseif re == "n" or "N" then
    print("Ok...")
end
```

Comment: The conditionals there are wrong, eg `re == "y" or "Y"` should be `re == "y" or re == "Y"`. It's probably good to be aware that we can check `re:lower() == "y"`  too.

Answer (score 0):

try to use folowing code

`m=io.read()` 
 `if m=="yes" then`
 `(insert functions here)`
`end`

Answer (score -2):

```
print("Continue (y/n)?")
re = io.read()
if re == "y" or "Y" then
    (Insert stuff here)
elseif re == "n" or "N" then
    print("Ok...")
end
```

From the bit of lua that I've done (not a lot), I'm going to say that using both uppercase and lowercase letters is redundant if you use string.sub.

```
print("Continue? (y/n)")
local re = io.read()

--[[Can you get string.sub from a local var? 
If so, this works. I'm unfamiliar with io(game 
lua uses GUI elements and keypresses in place of the CLI.]]

if re.sub == "y" then
    --do stuff
if re.sub == "n" then
    --do other stuff
end
```

That should work.

Comment: `re.sub` will resolve to the function `string.sub` & always be unequal to `"y"` or `"n"`. Besides, string matching is case sensitive. At best you can do `re:match("[nN]")` and `re:match("[yY]")`