# How to pause a Lua script?

Tags: lua

Is it possible to completely pause a lua script to catch errors, etc..?

Kind of like in batch/dos you just type pause, then it waits for any key to be pressed.

Any possibility to do so in Lua?

Comment: Looks like you can take some ideas from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689566/keypress-event-in-lua

Comment: You could issue OS `pause` command, but that's not portable.

Comment: If `pause` is available, use `os.execute("pause")`.

Comment: Reading a character from standard input is a slightly more portable alternative I think. Though you may not actually have a standard input available to read from.

Comment: `io.write"Press Enter to continue...";io.read()`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815163/lua-get-command-line-input-from-user.

Comment: If the script is being developed then [debug.debug()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.10) might be a good alternative. Continue execution with `cont`. Note: Some Lua environments don't support all standard libraries..